# Adding a parameter to a line with Ansible with lineinfile function and regexp

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to add the parameter

> *--log-opt max-size=5M*

to an existing line within a file and first want to check if this parameter is already set:

```
regexp: "^OPTIONS=(?!.*?(--log-opt max-size).*)"
```

I've tested with that teststring, on 3 different online testers it matched as required:

```
OPTIONS='--log-opt max-size=5M --selinux-enabled --signature-verification=False'
```

here's the complete playbook:

```
  - name: "adding limiting parameter for container log-sizes"
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/sysconfig/docker
      backrefs: true
      state: present
      regexp: "^OPTIONS=(?!.*?(--log-opt max-size).*)"
      line: "OPTIONS='--log-opt max-size=5M \\1'"
```

Ansible breaks with an exception, tried it with Ansible 2.6.5 and 2.7 guess it's rather a synthax than a binary issue.
Have been trying for so long :/

Want also to get the quotes after OPTIONS= to be checked in the regexp 
(should be OPTIONS='*any content* ')

Any ideas ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[**(?<=')[^']+**](https://regex101.com/r/wrvyvQ/4/)

This pattern will get all the line after the quotes on OPTIONS=.

- (?<='): Search the ' and pos it after found it.
- [^']+ : Match everything one to unlimited times except if found a '.

Said that, if you want to check if the line, you can try another regex, like **/--log-opt max-size=/** testing the output line got from the match above.

Comment: have tried my best, haven't made it to get that regex running. Is there any chance to add a second regex for a lineinfile function at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that Group 1 doesn't match, the exception was because of that.
Maybe not the smartest way, but worked around it and updated the regex to:  `^OPTIONS='(?!.*?(--log-opt max-size))(.*)` had to adapt the replacement line as well: `OPTIONS='--log-opt max-size=5M\\2`.

Complete playbook section now:

`- name: "adding limiting parameter for container log-sizes"
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/sysconfig/docker
      backrefs: true
      state: present
      regexp: "^OPTIONS='(?!.*?(--log-opt max-size))(.*)"
      line: "OPTIONS='--log-opt max-size=5M \\2"`